# How to organise data and run nerlovian model

Tags: multiple-regression, stata

I am trying to estimate the price elasticity of supply for small scale farmers in Malawi and I have time series data for 34 years. I have two problems: First, the prices are very low such that when I take their logs am getting negative values, as a remedy i added 1 to each value and i got positive logs but i don't know how to interprete the result with the 1 that I added. Second i want to find out the specific way of estimating the model in `Stata`, I just used regress. I will appreciate your help

Answer (score 7):

Negative logarithms are *not* a problem. All they mean is that your prices are less than 1 in whatever currency you are using. This is basic mathematics: e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Thus you should not add 1 before taking logarithms.

That said, I don't know how you get price elasticity out of time series because I am not an economist, but I suspect no harm would be done by your telling us more about your dataset, notably what variables you have.

Answer (score 5):

The non-linear structural equations of the Nerlove model reduce to a simple linear equation:
\begin{equation}
\ln y_{it}=\beta_0+\beta_1 \ln y_{it-1}+\beta_2 \ln y_{it-2}+\beta_3 \ln p_{t-1}+\beta_4 \ln x_{it} + \varepsilon_{it},
\end{equation}
where $x$ is any exogenous non-price variables (like rainfall). The coefficient on lagged price gives you the short-run price elasticity of supply, and you can interpret the effect as saying that for 1% increase in price, you get $\beta_3$% increase in output. You definitely don't need to add the one, like Nick pointed out. Don't take log of binary variables.

With panel data, `xtabond` can be used, but the dynamic panel route demands a fairly high level of technical sophistication. Applied folks will often estimate this using OLS like you did, even though this is not entirely correct.